# How to inject activity context in modules with koin dependency library

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, koin

I have a Util module as below, it requires the activity context [not application context] to do some of its functions.

How do I inject the activity context into it?

```
class MainPresenter internal constructor(private val iMainActivity: IActivity)  : IPresenter {

    //dependencies
    private val context = iMainActivity as AppCompatActivity

    private var util = UtilModule(context)         //<-- inject this
    private var httpClient = HttpClient(context)   //<-- inject this
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that a presenter should have a reference to an activity, or a reference to things that use an activity?

Answer (score 6):

In this case, as [@commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) said, it's not good that the presenter class depends on the activity.
The better solution with the injection can be like the following the structure:

```
class IActivity{

    private val utilModule: UtilModule by lazy { UtilModule(this@IActivity) }
    private val httpClient: HttpClient by lazy { HttpClient(this@IActivity) }

    private val presenter: MainPresenter by inject{ parametersOf(utilModel, 
    httpClient) }

}

class MainPresenter(private val util: UtilModule, private val httpClient: HttpClient)
```

Your module:

```
single { MainPresenter( it[0], it[1] ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append activity/fragment instance dynamic into scope instance registry with koin lifecycle extensions.

```
val definition = BeanDefinition(
    scopeDefinition = this._scopeDefinition,
    primaryType = T::class,
    kind = Kind.Single,
    definition = { instance() }
)

val instanceMap = lifecycleScope._instanceRegistry.instances as HashMap<IndexKey, InstanceFactory<*>>
val factory = SingleInstanceFactory(this._koin, definition)
instanceMap[indexKey(T::class, null)] = factory
```

Then inject it in scope defination:

```kotlin
scope<SomeActivity> {
    // inject activity with Scope.get()
    scoped { SomeModule(get()) }
}
```

Finally, inject with lifecycleScope:

```kotlin
val someModule: SomeModule by lifecycleScope.inject()
```

I wrote a demo to explain how it works: 
https://github.com/twiceyuan/KoinAndroidComponentInject